# How do I set the background on a SQP Server 2008 R2 SSRS report using a formula

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing a report that incorporates a graphical header on only the first page, and I wanted to utilize two different embedded graphics as page backgrounds.  My initial (failed) attempt was to:

1. right click on the page background
2. choose the Body Properties

   [image: Context Menu for the report body]
3. Add a Fill Background image Formula

   [image: Report Body Properties dialog]

   as follows:

   =IIF(Globals!PageNumber > 1, background, first_background)

When I attempted to render the report I received the following error:

[image: error message for using a global variable in the body]

Am I just out of luck with this?  Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally for this kind of stuff you'd use indirection. That is you'd have a hidden text box on the report header. This will have `Globals!PageNumber`

Then you set the background property by referring to the `ReportItems!MyHiddenTextBox.Value`.

I haven't tried it for background but it's a common thing to do in SSRS to workaround scope/region issues. [This example is the reverse: putting a value into a header/footer](http://www.andrewdenhertog.com/reporting-services/reporting-services-ssrs-get-data-value-into-page-headerfooter).  And [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/Bunch/archive/2008/03/05/data-into-a-ssrs-header-again.aspx). It *probably* works in the other direction :-)

Comment: Thanks!  I will give it a try and update the question with the solution.

Comment: what was the solution ?